# Terraform AWS EC2 Instance stops installing remote commands because of Ubuntu Kernel Upgrade

Tags: aws

I'm trying to boot up an EC2 instance on AWS using Terraform. So far the config is good and the instance works. SSH into the instance also works through Terraform security groups etc.

However I want to install some commands via remote-exec provisioner in Terraform as non-interactive mode.

This partially works, until i get hit randomly by this "pending kernel upgrade" popup. The Terraform then freezes and waits forever because it requires user input.

How can I set to ignore this message?

[image]

Here is my `aws.tf`:

```
# EC2 instance
resource "aws_instance" "spring_boot_server" {
    ami           = var.ami_ubuntu_22_04_lts
    instance_type = var.instance_type

    tags = {
        Name = "SpringBootServer-${local.project_name}"
    }

    # Add a reference to the security group created below
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_ssh.name]

    # To be able to SSH into this instance
    key_name = var.ssh_key_name

    connection {
        type        = "ssh"
        user        = "ubuntu"
        private_key = file("~/.aws/aws/keypairs/devops.pem")
        host        = self.public_ip
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
            # Update package lists and upgrade packages without prompts
            "sudo apt update -y",
            "sudo apt upgrade -y",

            # Add and install Adoptium OpenJDK repository without prompts
            "wget -qO - https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/adoptium.asc > /dev/null",
            "echo \"deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/adoptium.asc] https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb $(awk -F= '/^VERSION_CODENAME/{print$2}' /etc/os-release) main\" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptium.list > /dev/null",
            "sudo apt update -y",

            # Install Java JDK 17 without prompts and print installed Java version
            "sudo apt install temurin-17-jdk -y",
            "java --version",

            # Add and install Jenkins repository without prompts
            "curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null",
            "echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null",
            "sudo apt-get update -y",

            # Install Jenkins without prompts
            "sudo apt-get install jenkins -y",

            # Start Jenkins service and print the status to verify that it has started
            "sudo systemctl start jenkins",
            "sudo systemctl status jenkins",

            # Print the initial Jenkins password
            "sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword",
        ]
    }
}

# Create a security group to allow SSH access
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_ssh" {
    name        = "allow-ssh"
    description = "Allow SSH inbound traffic"

    ## SSH inbound rule
    ingress {
        from_port   = 22
        to_port     = 22
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    # Jenkins (port 8080) inbound rule
    ingress {
        from_port   = 8080
        to_port     = 8080
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    # Outbound rule for all traffic (0.0.0.0/0 means allow all outbound traffic)
    egress {
        from_port = 0
        to_port   = 0

        # This indicates all protocols
        protocol = "-1"

        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not upgrade the kernel?

Comment: I don't care about it, i just want to create an EC2 instance through terraform using AWS's ubuntu 22.04 latest version as of now

Comment: Well that's stopping you from running remote commands and you have to get it out of the way to proceed

Comment: How do i solve this with remote-exec commands and have no user input interactivity?

Comment: Taking a look at the issue you **need to restart** the server to load the new kernel. That is something you have to determine how best such a process will affect you service